# How to read nested txt file from Spring Integration File

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have config file like below :-

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@Configuration
@EnableIntegrationManagement
public class FileSourceConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileSourceConfig.class);

    private FileSourceProperties properties;

    Source source;

    public FileSourceConfig(FileSourceProperties properties, Source source) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamicRegexPatternFilter getFilter(){
        return new DynamicRegexPatternFilter();
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel linesChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /* To poll the file for every given TimeUnit.SECONDS */
    @Bean(name = { "defaultPoller", PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER })
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(properties.getPollPeriod(), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileInboundChannelFlow() {
        FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec messageSourceSpec = Files
                .inboundAdapter(Paths.get(this.properties.getDirectory()).toFile());

        messageSourceSpec = messageSourceSpec.filter(getFilter());

        //messageSourceSpec.regexFilter(this.properties.getFilenameRegex());
        messageSourceSpec.preventDuplicates(this.properties.isPreventDuplicates());

        //Setting random UUID as messagekey
        IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(messageSourceSpec)
                .split(new FileSplitter(true, true))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY,"T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()"));

        return flowBuilder.<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass,
                m -> m.channelMapping(FileSplitter.FileMarker.class, "markers.input").channelMapping(String.class,
                        "lines.input"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow lines() {
        return f -> f.headerFilter("file_originalFile") .channel(source.output());
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logErrors() {
        return f -> f.log(LoggingHandler.Level.ERROR, "error", m -> "Error in sending message :"+m.getPayload());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow markers() {
        return f -> f.log().<FileSplitter.FileMarker>filter(m -> m.getMark().equals(FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END))
                .handle(m -> m.getHeaders(), e -> e.id("archive").advice(afterAdvice()));
    }}
```

Can someone please suggest how to read file from inbound/a/a.txt and inblund/b/b.txt

Please find the filter code below:-

```
public class DynamicRegexPatternFilter extends AbstractFileListFilter<File> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicRegexPatternFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private FileSourceProperties properties;

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        String[] quaterRange = {"[0][0-3]", "[0][4-6]", "[0][7-9]", "[1][0-2]"};
        String fileNameRegex = this.properties.getFilenameRegex();
        //logic here

        return Pattern.compile(fileNameRegex)
                .matcher(file.getName())
                .matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the `RecursiveDirectoryScanner`.
By default the `FileReadingMessageSource` comes with a `DefaultDirectoryScanner`. So, you just need to configure your `messageSourceSpec` with that `RecursiveDirectoryScanner`:

```
FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec messageSourceSpec =
                Files.inboundAdapter(Paths.get(this.properties.getDirectory()).toFile())
                        .scanner(new RecursiveDirectoryScanner());
```

Also see docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#directory-scanning-and-polling

Comment: Hello Im getting below error :- When using an external scanner the 'filter' and 'locker' options should not be used. Instead, set these options on the external DirectoryScanner:

Comment: And? Why don’t follow that recommendation then ?

Comment: On the other thought we can introduce a convenient `recursive()` option for better end-use experience. Doesn’t look like we ha a strong bean requirements for this scanner...

Comment: Here is the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3495